# Когда слово «двоими» можно использовать?

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, значение-слов, числительные

Когда можно использовать слово «двоими», и существует ли оно? Можно привести  пример, когда говорим только «двоими», но не можем сказать «двумя»?

Answer (score 1):

> Можно привести пример, когда говорим только «двоими», но не можем сказать «двумя»?

```
Договор был подписан двоими - Васей и Петей.
```

Но

```
Хотя много людей участвовало в дебатах, договор был подписан двумя - Васей и Петей.
```

Comment: Вроде бы корректно.  Собирательные числительные в косвенных падежах заменяются количественными.  Но  субстантивированные собирательные числительные используются во всех падежах.

Answer (score 0):

**Двое-двоим-двоими / два-двум-двумя.**

**В каких случаях употребляется двое, в каких два?**

Двое-двоим - кто?-кому? ~ вы-вами, они-им, их, эти-этим, тех *~ заменимо на* **вместе.**

Два-двум-двумя - сколько-скольки?-сколькими?(хотя, я бы говорил сколькью?, но пишут, что это неграмотно)

Двоими отсюда - кем? ~ вами, ими, с ними. ~ и только потом сколькими?

Двоим - кому? двум - скольки? Помог этим людям - помог двоим людям, помог обоим, помог им; помог нескольким людям - помог двум людям / помог двоим из них, из тех.

> Так для чего же не быть двоим сердцам? Сковорода.

> ...двоим работникам нетрудно разрыть ее в один день и переловить лисят... Аксаков.

> Однако, позвольте, позвольте... двоим нельзя один и тот же участок определить; надо, чтоб один из вас пожертвовал, оказал великодушие — взял похуже. Тургенев.

> Да разве он один вам двоим не под силу? Толстой.(вам двоим = вам вместе)

Двойня - родившиеся вместе.

Родилось два ребенка - разродилась двумя / родилась двойня ~ родилось двое ~ разродилась двоими.

**Два-двум - употребляется как счетное числительное по отношению к объектам или понятиям. Двое-двоим - по отношению к субъектам, которые обязательно одушевленные или одушевляются, также двое заменимо по смыслу на "вместе".** *Двоими - форма от двоим в косвенном падеже.*

> ...а с ним на той же телеге ехали два палача, Алешка да Терешка, и воткнут на телеге топор и палаш, да два ножа, а около телеги шли с ружьем... И. А. Желябужский.

Если бы было двое, то: ехали двое палачей - Алёшка и Терёшка - ехали они палачи. А тут ехали палачи - сколько? - два.

> Да Тихменевы два брата ранены, и люди боярские взяты ж и ранены немногие.

Если двое, то: да *двое братьев* Тихменевых раненные, - необходимо и согласование во множественном - братьев, в отличие от *два брата* - два чего? - брата, р.п. ед. ч. ~ двоим братьям Тихменевым нанесли ранения - двоим кому? - братьям, д.п. мн. ч.

**Про двоими**:

> Всего их, Комаровых сестер и братьев, семеро, но мы дружим с двоими. Григорян.

Мы дружим с кем? - с двоими.

Двоими детьми, двоими дядями, двоими лицами и тп. с указанием на людей.

> Ниловна, идите вместе, а? За двоими труднее следить, — хорошо? — Иду! — ответила мать. Горький.

Когда **они вместе**, за ними следить труднее / а не "их два", поэтому за ними трудно следить.

> Комаровых две сестры: Катя и Лена. Всего их, Комаровых сестер и братьев, семеро, но мы дружим с двоими. Анаит Григорян.

Мы дружим с двоими ~ мы с двоими вместе - мы и они это МЫ. Двоими употребляется при совместном действии или состоянии с другими людьми или кем-то одушевленным.
Я иду с двумя сумками - я иду вместе двумя с сумками - звучит комично, сумки становятся одушевленными и начинают идти сами. Получается, что *я иду с сумками*, также как *сумки идут* со мной - мы с сумками идем вместе!
Я гуляю с двумя своими котами - Шариком и Бобиком. - я гуляю вместе с ними, а они гуляют со мной - мы гуляем вместе: я и двое котов, - может быть, мы все - коты?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149111/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.